# Add Click Event to TextBox in GridView Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to access the textbox that is in my `Gridview` and add a click event. I added a click event to a textbox that is outside of the `Gridview` with no issues using `jQuery`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID = "dcrTxtBoxAll" runat="server"
    style="Z-INDEX: 120; LEFT: 783px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 111px; width: 432px; height: 71px;"
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
    Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' 
    Visible="false" 
    TextMode="MultiLine">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // This function adds a click listener to the dcrTxrBoxAll textbox. When the textbox is clicked the update button and the GridView Rows textboxes are disabled
    $("#dcrTxtBoxAll").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#cmdUpdate").val('Update All'); // Changed the button text

        // Loop through the GridView and disable each text box
        $("#GridView1 tr").each(function ()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $dcrTextBox = $("#dcrTextBox", $this); // Get the textbox at each row
            $dcrTextBox.prop("disabled", true); // Disable the textbox
        });

        $("*").unbind("click"); // Removes all click handlers added by javascript from every element
        $("[onclick]").removeAttr("onclick"); // Finds all elements with an 'onclick' attribute, and removes that attribute
    });
</script>
```

I tried a similar approach, but I can not get it to work.

Here is the `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
              runat="server"
              style="Z-INDEX: 120; LEFT: 410px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 244px; width: 698px; height: 251px;"
              BackColor="DeepSkyBlue"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              BorderStyle="Solid"
              BorderColor="Black"
              AllowSorting="True"
              PageSize="15"
              AllowMultiRowSelection="true"
              ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
              GridLines="None">
  <RowStyle backcolor="White" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkHeader"
                      runat="server"
                      AutoPostBack="true"
                      OnCheckedChanged="ChkHeader_CheckedChanged" />
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkEmpty"
                      runat="server"
                      AutoPostBack="true"
                      OnCheckedChanged="ChkEmpty_CheckedChanged" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestorId"
                    HeaderText="Requestor Id"
                    ReadOnly="True">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName"
                    HeaderText="File Name"
                    ReadOnly="True">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FolderName"
                    HeaderText="Sub Folder Name"
                    ReadOnly="True">
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"
                   Width="24px"
                   VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDt"
                    HeaderText="Uploaded Dt"
                    ReadOnly="True">
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"
                   Width="48px"></HeaderStyle>
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"
                   Width="96px" />
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description of Change/Reason"
                       ItemStyle-Width="300px">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="dcrLabel"
                   runat="server"
                   Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="dcrTextBox"
                     runat="server"
                     ClientIDMode="Static"
                     Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'
                     Visible="false"
                     TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is what I tried to access the textbox that is in the `GridView`. I can't seem to get it to register the click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dcrTextBox').on('click', function() {
        alert('Hello');
    });
</script>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that text box id is "dcrTextBox".

However, since it is repeated in the GridView many times, then which row and which instance of the TextBox would the above refer to?

And keep in mind that the HTML standard is to NOT allow controls on the same page with the same id. Hence, if you have 10 rows, then you will see in the markup 10 rows, and EACH of the controls on the row will have their own auto-generated ID.

However, when one drops a control, a text box, or just about any control into a web page?

Why use jQuery to wire up some event to a control? I see no real reason to do this, and now you have MUCH MORE difficult markup to read, since you have a button, or control like a text box, and now SOME OTHER place in the markup in that page, you have to know, have to find, have to look for that jQuery that wires up that event. So, in the case of a button, or text box, then in most cases it’s better to just add the event to the control.

Hence when you the developer are looking at that control, then you can see that some event is attached to that control. And thus, you don't have to go looking someplace else on the page to know/see/find that some jQuery code now decided to wire up some event to that control. This increases the context and mental workload of the developer, and makes debugging such pages rather difficult.

To be 100% clear? The idea of jQuery being able to attach and wire up control events on a page, and do so against many controls is a REALLY fantastic feature of jQuery. So, I highly recommend using jQuery selectors to wire up events on a page.

However, when this ability to select multiple controls and wire up events to those controls is not required, then just use a regular plain Jane event defined in the given control's markup.

One of the several bonus results of defining the click event for the text box is we are free to pass additional parameters with the given click event.

So, we can have markup say like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server"
            TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                onclick='<%# $"myrowclick(this,{Eval("ID")},{Container.DataItemIndex});return false" %>'
            >
        </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So, in above we pass the control "this", we pass the database row PK id, and we pass the row index.

The above markup is thus part of a GridView like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" 
    Width="55%"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server"
                        TextMode="MultiLine" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                            onclick='<%# $"myrowclick(this,{Eval("ID")},{Container.DataItemIndex});return false" %>'
                        >
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bookings">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="Bookings" 
                    class="btn myshadow"
                    OnClientClick="return callme(this)"
                    OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    GVHotels.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                                WHERE ID IN (select Hotel_id FROM BOOKINGS)
                                ORDER BY HotelName")
    GVHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And we now have this result:

[image]

Hence, since you have that text box being "repeated" for you by the GridView control, then might as well simply add one click event in the markup. As above shows, this has the added advantage of passing values like the database PK ID, the row index, and of course using "this" for the control passed.

Comment: great answer. Which tool do you use to make this gif?

Comment: I use screen to gif. This one:  https://www.screentogif.com/